# Logs and events: How are arguments of "watch" defined?

Tags: solidity, events, logs

In order to watch an event we can use:

```
var temp;
eventx.watch (function(error, result){ temp = result.args.val.toNumber();});
```

**Question** 1: What is the role of:

```
function(error, result){ temp = result.args.val.toNumber();}
```

and why does not it have any name?

**Question** 2: What does it return?

In general, what are the arguments of *watch* function?

Answer (score 1):

1. This is referred to as an 'anonymous function', a function without a name. It doesn't have a name because in this context it doesn't need one as we never need to refer to it outside of this scope. In this context it is used as a 'callback' which will be called when the watch function observes an event occurring and passes it to the callback function as either an `error` or a `response`.
2. The doc for events in web3js pre 1.0, which I believe is what the function above is using, [can be found here](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#contract-events) and it specifies the parameters and return values. You should also check out the web3js 1.0 [doc for events](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth-contract.html#events) as there is a couple of new methods there. They also specify the parameters of the functions and what they return.